# ENVIO SOAP XML ERRADO PHP

Tags: php, soap, soapclient

Estou tentando enviar dados para um ***webservice*** e não consigo.

```
$url = "http://plataformasintese.com:8085/IntegrationService.asmx?WSDL";
$wsdl = $url;
$client = new SOAPClient($wsdl,array("trace" => true, "exceptions" => true, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));

try
{
    $res = $client->EnviarOfertas($dom_xml);
    $results = json_decode(json_encode($res), true);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Montei a requisição no ***SOAPUI*** e ficou assim e funcionou, mas nao consigo fazer no php

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:EnviarOfertas>
         <tem:xmlDoc>
            <Cotacao>
               <Tp_Movimento>1</Tp_Movimento>
               <Dt_Gravacao>13/08/2019 15:04:03</Dt_Gravacao>
               <Cd_Fornecedor>18269125000187</Cd_Fornecedor>
               <Cd_Cotacao>COT3007-353</Cd_Cotacao>
               <Cd_Condicao_Pagamento>1</Cd_Condicao_Pagamento>
               <Nm_Usuario>BIOHOSP PRODUTOS HOSPITALARES LTDA</Nm_Usuario>
               <Ds_Observacao>-</Ds_Observacao>
               <Qt_Prz_Minimo_Entrega>5</Qt_Prz_Minimo_Entrega>
               <Vl_Minimo_Pedido>0.00</Vl_Minimo_Pedido>
               <Ds_Observacao_Fornecedor/>
               <Produtos_Cotacao>
                  <Produto_Cotacao>
                     <Id_Produto_Sintese>7930</Id_Produto_Sintese>
                     <Cd_Produto_Comprador>001594</Cd_Produto_Comprador>
                     <Marcas_Oferta>
                        <Marca_Oferta>
                           <Id_Marca>203</Id_Marca>
                           <Ds_Marca>NOVA FARMA</Ds_Marca>
                           <Qt_Embalagem>50</Qt_Embalagem>
                           <Vl_Preco_Produto>1.2263</Vl_Preco_Produto>
                           <Ds_Obs_Oferta_Fornecedor/>
                           <Cd_ProdutoERP>26677</Cd_ProdutoERP>
                        </Marca_Oferta>
                     </Marcas_Oferta>
                  </Produto_Cotacao>
               </Produtos_Cotacao>
            </Cotacao>
         </tem:xmlDoc>
      </tem:EnviarOfertas>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

### Na documentação:

```html
POST /IntegrationService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: plataformasintese.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/EnviarOfertas"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <EnviarOfertas xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <xmlDoc>xml</xmlDoc>
    </EnviarOfertas>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Retorna algum erro?

Comment: Não, nenhum erro, porém quando eu monto a requisição no PHP com o soapCall ele nao está colocando os argumentos corretamente.